# Edit httpd.conf - Require/include no longer works

Tags: php, apache

Running latest Zend Server on Windows 7x64, I was playing around with different ways to sync htdocs into dropbox and edited two lines of httpd.conf.

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2/htdocs">
```

with various symlinks, dropbox locations, etc.

Put it back to the way it was and php includes and require no longer work.  I know the scripts are fine as the exact same scripts work on my desktop with the exact same development environment.

I put all my usernames/passwords/database names/etc in a php file that is generally stored outside the htdocs directory.

```
require_once('constants.php');
```

(In the same dir for purposes of troubleshooting, have tried everything from $_SERVER to **dir**.

Throws this error:

**Warning**:  require_once(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\index.php** on line **17**

**Fatal error**:  require_once(): Failed opening required '1' (include_path='.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library') in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\index.php** on line **17**

- Scripts are working fine on another machine with exact same software.
- For the purposes of testing scripts, even require_once in same dir doesn't work.
- Made a backup of httpd.conf before changing, put it back with no effect.
- Copied httpd.conf off healthy machine, no change.
- Completely re-installed the entire zend package twice, no change.

At a loss as to what could be causing this.  Any ideas?

---

This is out of the box from the healthy machine, # removed:

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2/htdocs"

Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
directory (and its subdirectories). 

First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
features.  

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
below.


This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.

<Directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2/htdocs">

Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All", 
or any combination of:
Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews

Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
doesn't give it to you.

The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
for more information.

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit

AllowOverride None

Controls who can get stuff from this server.

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

No quotes are used in Apache config IE:

```
   ServerName yoursite.com
   DocumentRoot C:\www\your_site
   <Directory C:\www\your_site>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            ... rest of stuff
   </Directory>
```

In addition your include may need the absolute path depending on you Apache settings .. IE

```
 require_once('C:\www\your_site\outside_http_docs\constants.php');
```

Comment: This is not correct: Apache configs perfectly work with quotes

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  Windows permissions requiring file outside the scope of htdocs.